# Force an actor to obey the width set in table.add(actor).width()

Tags: libgdx

I am setting the width of actor in `table.add(actor).width(width)`. The padding is set to 1% of screen width. This is the result I get:[image]

As you can see, spacing between actors is way beyond 1% . I tried using `fill()` methods but it didn't work. I also tried `setFillParent(true)` on the actor, no success. What is going on here? This is the complete code. The only spacing between actors should be the one I set with padding.  How do I achieve this?

```
private void createScrollPane(){
        texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle fibs=new ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle();
        fibs.imageUp=new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(texture));
        button1= new ImageButton(fibs);
        button2= new ImageButton(fibs);
        button3= new ImageButton(fibs);

        button1.setPosition(0, 0);
        button2.setPosition(0, 0);
        button3.setPosition(0, 0);
        scrollTable=new Table();
        scrollTable.setBounds(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.03f,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*0.94f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        scrollTable.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.03f, 50);
        scrollTable.add(button1).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.3f).padLeft(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.01f).fill();
        scrollTable.add(button2).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.3f).padLeft(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.01f).padRight(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.01f).fillX();
        scrollTable.add(button3).width(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.3f).padRight(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.01f).fill();

        stage.addActor(scrollTable);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageButton` is a `Button` with an `Image` on top of it. If you just want a button then use the `Button` class and set the `up` drawable to the drawable you want it to be. Note that you can enable debug drawing of the stage or table to visualize what is going on.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question in a meaningful manner.  His function calls affect the layout of table (and its cells), not the actors, and he's not realizing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your function calls are affecting the Table's *cells*, not the actors in the cells.

Call `scrollTable.setDebug(true)` to see the cells, padding, etc.  You'll be happy to find your function calls are working, just on the cells rather than their contents.

The next step is to build a composite layout with widgets which allow you to expand the buttons but maintain them in a horizontal alignment.  You *might* be able to accomplish that with just a table if you battle the cells hard enough, I'm not sure.

What I did was to use a Table, then add a HorizontalGroup.  The HorizontalGroup goes within a *cell* on the Table.  Inside the HorizontalGroup I add my buttons.  Laying out the buttons the way I want within the HorizontalGroup is far easier than doing it via the Table.

For an ImageButton you can explicitly set the `minHeight` and `minWidth` of the style, which will forcibly scale the attached Image.